# Creating Simple Goods Movement Screen With Web IDE

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am using the full stack web IDE to create simple form that will post a 561 initial stock goods movement.  I am not sure what I am missing as far as my bindings.  The controller seems to be doing what it is supposed to but the JSON that is produced is incorrect.

The correct JSON looks like this:

```js
{
"PostingDate": "2018-08-27T00:00:00",
"GoodsMovementCode": "05",
"to_MaterialDocumentItem": [{
  "Material": "MZ-FG-E11",
  "Plant": "1710",
  "StorageLocation": "171A",
  "GoodsMovementType": "561",
  "Batch" : "0000000013",
  "QuantityInEntryUnit": "12",
  "ShelfLifeExpirationDate":"2018-08-27T00:00:00",
  "ManufactureDate": "2018-05-27T00:00:00"
  }]
}
```

A snippet of my view in the web ide is as follows:

```html
   <f:SimpleForm class="editableForm" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" editable="true" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" id="newEntitySimpleForm" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" maxContainerCols="2" minWidth="1024" title="{= ${viewModel>/mode} === 'edit'? 'Edit API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV': 'New API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV'}">
    <f:content>
     <Label text="Posting Date" required="false"/>
     <DatePicker name="PostingDate" value="{ path: 'PostingDate', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime'}" id="PostingDate_id" enabled="true" visible="true"/>
     
     <Label text="Goods Movement Code" required="false"/>
     <Input name="GoodsMovementCode" id="GoodsMovementCode_id" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement" enabled="true" visible="true" value="{ path: 'GoodsMovementCode', type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , constraints:{ maxLength:2 } }"/>
     
     <Label text="Material" required="true"/>
     <Input name="Material" id="MaterialDocument_id" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement" enabled="{= ${viewModel>/mode} === 'edit'? false: true}" visible="true" value="{ **path: 'to_MaterialDocumentItem>Material'** , type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , constraints:{ maxLength:10, nullable:false } }" cd:w5g.dt.context="/A_MaterialDocumentItem"/>
     
     <Label text="Plant" required="false"/>
     <Input name="Plant" id="Plant_id" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement" enabled="true" visible="true" value="{ path: 'Plant', type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , constraints:{ maxLength:2 } }"/>
```

When testing this form I received the following information from chrome developer tools with an error 400 Bad Request:

```js
PostingDate: "/Date(1536642000000)/", GoodsMovementCode: "1",…}
Batch:"7"
GoodsMovementCode:"1"
GoodsMovementType:"5"
Plant:"3"
PostingDate:"/Date(1536642000000)/"
QuantityInEntryUnit:"6"
StorageLocation:"4"
__metadata:
{type: "API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV.A_MaterialDocumentHeaderType",…}
type:"API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV.A_MaterialDocumentHeaderType"
uri:"/My187/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_MATERIAL_DOCUMENT_SRV/A_MaterialDocumentHeader('id-1536693644259-199')"
```

My question is:

1. How do I get the bindings to produce the "to_MaterialDocumentItem" as shown in the validated JSON?

Comment: As this question is not directly related to the the S/4HANA Cloud SDK, can you please elaborate where you see the connection? Then we might be able to support in this issue.
From a first view it looks like you received a valid OData response from your system, do you have any more specifics why this might return a 400 code? Can you in general provide more details?

Comment: Hi Goodman Darren, can you pls let us know if you are using the S/4HANA Cloud SDK in your context? To me it appears you do not.